# counter in the loop, after finish start again

Tags: android, loops, count, counter

I need a counter that when it reaches the maximum value, starts to count from the beginning. I tried some if statements, but i am new in android developing and my attempts was wrong. Please help me a little. Thank you

Comment: Good luck! When you have an actual, specific, programming-related question, head on back.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
int maxValue = 10;
for (int i = 0; i <= maxValue; i++)
{
    if ( i == maxValue)
    {
        i = 0;
    }
}
```